# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable вот в чем ошибка - new_clan_id=int(new_clan_id[0])

Tags: python

try:
name = str(message.text.split()[2])
if len(name) <= 30 and len(name) >= 4:
pass
else:
await message.reply('‼️Название клана должно быть не меньше 4 символов и не больше 30 символов')
return
except:
await message.reply('‼️ Не хватает аргументов!\nПример: клан создать название ')
return
new_clan_id = cursor.execute(
"SELECT new_clan_id from clans_id ")
new_clan_id=cursor.fetchone()
new_clan_id=int(new_clan_id[0])
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET balance={balance - 100_000_000_000_000} WHERE user_id=?",(message.from_user.id,))
cursor.execute(
f'INSERT INTO clans VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);',(1,new_clan_id,name,0,1,new_clan_id,0,0,0,0))
cursor.execute(
f'INSERT INTO clan VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', (user_id, user_name, "SOZD", new_clan_id,name))
connect.commit()
await message.reply(
f'️ {user_name} Вы успешно создали клан',
parse_mode='html')
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE clans_id SET new_clan_id={new_clan_id+1}")
connect.commit()
else:
await message.reply(f' {user_name} Нищий не может создать клан (недостаточно средств)\n Стоимость: 100.000.000.000.000₽(100трлн) ',
parse_mode='html')
else:
await message.reply(f'‼️ {user_name} вы уже в клане',parse_mode='html')

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.